# How to Define in the column the two keywords are found get it in laravel

Tags: laravel

```
Model::where([
    'user_id' => Auth::id(),
    'status' => ['New', 'In Progress']
])->get();
```

this Eloquent query is getting only one record where in my database there are two records is exists

Comment: You probably don't have a model where the status is `New` *and* `In Progress`. Take a look into [whereIn](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#additional-where-clauses)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`where`, in this way, is saying: `status` is `New` and `In progress` which makes no sense. I'm surprised it finds any records.

```php
Model::where('user_id', Auth::id())
    ->whereIn('status', ['New', 'In Progress'])
    ->get();
```

Comment: btw, it finds a record because it isn't doing an 'and', it is only using the first element of the array for the value